# Issue in JMeter : Getting "Frame size error/Invalid frame length" in the response for HTTP2 plugin

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Solution Tried :
Tried changing content length in header manager
Getting this issue in the redirected page
Tried changing the heap size in JMeter property file.

None of solutions are fixing the above issue. Is anyone gone through these kind of issue in JMeter 5.4.3 http2 plugin?

JMeter response page attached for reference.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj2G0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question doesn't tell the full story and your problem cannot be reproduced.

Try [increasing JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for the [HTTP2 Plugin](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-http2-plugin) and Jetty by adding the next lines to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2" level="debug"/>
<Logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="debug"/>
```

restart JMeter and re-run your test. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries and update your question with full log file.

If you fail to see the failure reason from the log files you can raise an issue via [HTTP2 Plugin Github project page](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-http2-plugin/issues)